# MSBuild Error: "The solution file has two projects named ..."

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, publish-profiles

I'm trying to figure out how to make MSBuild work so I can set up automated builds and would appreciate some help with this weird error.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and a Web Application project.
The solution has 8 different class libraries. 
I've got several Publish Profiles set up for my web project, I've been using these for a few months and they work flawlessly.

Now I'm trying to use MSBuild to execute one of my Publish Profiles.
This is the command I have at the moment:

```
MSBuild "C:\Projects\OD_CD_MIS\Release 6.10\Source\NCCDPHPMIS_Web_Build.sln"
 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="Dev Intranet"
```

This fails immediately with the following message:

> Build started 6/10/2015 11:18:01. C:\Projects\OD_CD_MIS\Release
>   6.10\Source\NCCDPHPMIS_Web_Build.sln : Solution file error MSB5004: T he solution file has two projects named "NCCDPHPMIS_BLL".
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Projects\OD_CD_MIS\Release 6.10\Source\NCCDPHPMIS_Web_Build.sln :
>   Solution file error MSB5004:  The solution file has two projects named
>   "NCCDPHPMIS_BLL".
>
> 0 Warning(s)
>      1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01

The first thing I checked for was two projects in the *.sln file with the same name and I don't see anything.
I went as far as to create a new solution file and add all my project files to that and I'm getting the same error.

I don't see what I'm missing. 
Does anybody know what else could cause this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely some project naming issue in your solution file.  Check for things like similar names except for punctuation like _ or ..  There appears to be some behavior that will treat blah_something and blah.something as the same thing and report this error.  [Source](https://therightjoin.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/msb4025-the-project-file-could-not-be-loaded-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-error-when-building-ssdt-project-in-teamcity/)

Comment: That was exactly my problem.

Solution had two projects: "NCCDPHPMIS_BLL" and "NCCDPHPMIS.BLL"

I know this is poor naming convention. We're in the process or replacing a VB Project "_" with a C# Project "."